# How to use my own autoloader instead of Composer's for unit testing?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, autoloader, spl-autoload-register

What is `bootstrap` for in phpunit.xml? How can I use my own autoloader instead of Composer's for unit testing?

Directory structure,

```
autoload/
Test/
vendor/
composer.json
phpunit.xml
```

Originals:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./Test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

composer.json,

```
{
    "require": {
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "stats": ""
        }
    }
}
```

Original test resutl,

[image]

Below is my own autoload class `autoload/ClassLoader.php`,

```
<?php
namespace MyVendor\Autoload;

class ClassLoader
{
    public function fetch( $directories ) 
    {
        spl_autoload_register( [$this, 'getClass'] );
    }

    private function getClass( $className )
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

My `phpunit.xml`, which I changed the `bootsrap` to `autoload/ClassLoader.php`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="autoload/ClassLoader.php">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./Test/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

When I run `phpunit` in my **CMD** and this is my test result,

[image]

It looks different from the original but it didn't say that it is failed. So is my test correct?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own **bootstrap.php** file, and use spl_autoload_register to register your autoloader:

```
// External
spl_autoload_register('ClassLoader::getClass');

// Internal
function autoload($className)
{
....
}
spl_autoload_register('autoload');
```

Then call this in your **phpunit.xml** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit colors="true" bootstrap="bootstrap.php">
   ...
```